# __subclasses__ not showing anything

Tags: python, python-import

I'm implementing a function that returns an object from the appropriate subclass. If I move `SubClass` from `base.py`, no subclasses appear for `__subclasses__`. Are they required to be in the same file?
Perhaps the fact that I'm never importing directly `subclass.py` hides the subclass from python? What can I do? I have even checked the attribute `__mro__` and `get_subclass` points to the right class.

```python
# project/main.py
from project.src.base import get_subclass

obj = get_subclass(cls,name) # Returns an object of a subclass of cls

# project/src/subclass.py
from project.src.base import BaseClass

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    pass

# project/src/base.py
def get_subclass(cls,name):
    subclss = cls.__subclasses__ # This is returning an empty list
    pass

class BaseClass(object):
    pass
```

Comment: Shouldn't `get_subclass` return something? And you'll need to import `project.src.subclass`.

Comment: Import where? It should return something but it doesn't. If I have 4 subclasses in different files, should I import each? I guess it'd make more sense then to keep them in one file.

Comment: Import at all. If the module with the subclass is never loaded, then the python interpreter can't know that a subclass exists.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Python only runs code of modules that are imported. If you move code to a different module but never import it, Python does not know about its contents.

You have to import the files containing the subclasses you want accessible.

```
# project/src/__init__.py
import project.src.base      # executes the ``BaseClass`` definition
import project.src.subclass  # executes the ``SubClass`` definition
```

Note that it does not really matter where you import these - they must be imported before you need `SubClass` to appear in `__subclasses__`, though.

Comment: After a few hours of head-scratching, I stumbled upon this realization.

Comment: just a note for those who reads, don't try to test it on the same file as your base class! test the result in a separate file.