# get subclasses of Django non-Model based class

Tags: python, django

I have following abstract model in Django project, which I don`t want to have as db tables:

```
class Base(object):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and one subclass:

```
class Sub(Base):
```

I trying to get Sub from Base by answeer from this question:
[How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

```
Base.__subclasses__()
```

But, I get only empty list. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found another question, where answer said, that you need to import each subclasses of Base, then they will be available for Python.

[__subclasses__ not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937772/subclasses-not-showing-anything)

Comment: Please use the built-in duplication function of SO rather than an answer.